# Why does lodash _.find() in AWS lambda behaves different when called directly then via API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, find, lodash, gateway

My lambda function contains this code:

```
var product = _.find(products, { id: productId })
```

Why does this code find a product when called directly in Lambda (via AWS Console Test) while it does not return anything when the same lambda is called via AWS API Gateway (also via AWS Console Test) with the exact same parameter productId?

I must have something to do with asynchronity because replacing all _.find() with for-loops work directly in Lambda as well as via API Gateway.

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      if (products[i] && products[i].id == productId) {
          var product = products[i]
          break;
      }
  }
```

Comment: how are you acessing `products` inside your function? Also, please post the relevant parts from your Lambda function to see how you are grabbing the products, etc.

Comment: I am fetching products from Elasticache

        `var products = await redisClient.get('products')
        if (products = JSON.parse(products )) {
            ....`

However the structure of products is not the cause because it is exactly identical when executed directly or via API gateway. The fact that it works with the for-loop confirms that the structure of products is not the cause.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?